# [ValidationException: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.]

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am learning play framework from

[Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/JavaTodoList)

It gives an error on 1st line of this code.

```
Form<Task> filledForm = taskForm.bindFromRequest();
if(filledForm.hasErrors()) {
return badRequest(
  views.html.index.render(Task.all(), filledForm)
);
} else {
Task.create(filledForm.get());
return redirect(routes.Application.tasks());  
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try injecting the form factory in the class

```
@Inject
FormFactory formFactory;
```

and in action try like this

```
Form<Task> filledForm = formFactory.form(Task.class).bindFromRequest();
```